# How do I force an SSIS package to NOT reuse execution plans?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I know in SQL Server that I can force an execution plan to recompiled when running a stored procedure.

However, I have an SSIS package that is running through the SQL Agent.  After some big changes to the data which it operates on, the package went from taking 3 minutes to run to taking 3 hours.  When I run the package manually in SSDT, or after the server has restarted, it runs fine.  After some troubleshooting, I believe it's because the cached execution plan it had was no longer correct for the data it's operating on.

It there a way to tell SQL Server that when it runs this particular SSIS package, it should recompile everything and get a fresh execution plan?  The data it operates on can vary wildly in size from day to day.

Many thanks.

Comment: You make it sound like this is a SSIS behavior - it is not. SSIS submits SQL. SQL Server then decides to reuse an execution plan.

Comment: It could also be [parameter sniffing](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html) at play. Unfortunately, we don't have enough information to provide actionable results as we don't know what the package is doing, what components are involved, how data is being retrieved, how it's being stored, how you've reached the conclusion it's a cached plan vs a host of other factors (concurrent activity, slow source, slow destination, network, log growth on target database, etc). But yes, adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` is hammer that will remove cached connection plans from the equation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a query to regenerate the query plan each time it is run, use `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`. You find this is commonly used for "Kitchen Sink" or "Catch-all Queries", to avoid bad query plan caching, such as like below:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.MyTable
WHERE (Column1 = @Variable1 OR @Variable1 IS NULL)
  AND (Column2 = @Variable2 OR @Variable2 IS NULL)
  AND (Column3 = @Variable3 OR @Variable2 IS NULL)
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

This will, of course, incur a cost to regenerate the query plan, which for complex queries can be costly as well (for "Catch-all" queries, it's then better to go down the dynamic SQL route).